# Is it possible to do variadic templates in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

That is, is there a type safe way to make a function f that can receive an arbitrary number of parameters and a function that receives them in bulk and would work in a type safe fashion?

Say, let's have

```
fun<R, T1> func(f: (T1)->R, arg1: T1) { f(arg1) }
fun<R, T1, T2> func(f: (T1, T2)->R, arg1: T1, arg2: T2) { f(arg1, arg2) }
...
```

except that there is only a single body for `func` that supports an arbitrary number of such arguments?

I can accept compile time processing if there is no other way (e.g. generate the specific number of arguments in use automatically, or use a script to manually generate for up to, say, 20 arguments)

Comment: It's not clear what the purpose of `func(...)` is since it always delegates to `f`. What would you have as a signature of `f` ?

Comment: Is `vararg` an option? https://kotlinlang.org/docs/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko `vararg` doesn't allow the parameters to have different arguments (in order to preserve type safety).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible from "within the language". As you are OK with generating sources, [Kotlin Poet](https://square.github.io/kotlinpoet/) may be of use.

Comment: Could it be called from Gradle or something? I'd like to use it within Android Studio...

Comment: Pretty sure it can. A common use case for poet is to generate/compile code for custom annotations during a build.